# JavaFX: Making an Object with a Shape and Text

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make an object that can be added to my pane.
This object would contain a Shape and some text.

through invoking:

```
pane#getChildren()#add(new TextEllipse(...))
```

it would add an Ellipse with text in the center to the referenced pane.

My class for such an object is represented below:

```
    public class TextEllipse extends ShapeEllipse {

        public TextEllipse(final String text, final double x, final double y) {
            super(text, x, y);
        }
 @Override
    protected Shape createShape() {
        final double PADDING = 10;
        final Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.setRadiusX(getText().getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2 + PADDING);
        ellipse.setRadiusY(10);
        ellipse.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        return ellipse;
    }
    }


public abstract class TextShape extends Pane {
    private final Text text;
    private final Shape shape;

    public TextShape(final String text, final double x, final double y) {
        this.text = new Text(x, y, text);
        shape = createShape();
    }

    protected abstract Shape createShape();

    public Text getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Shape getBackgroundShape() {
        return shape;
    }
}
```

I've followed d.j. brown's method - however, when I invoke

```
pane#getChildren()#add(new TextEllipse(...))
```

Nothing shows up on the canvas.

However, when I do:

```
pane#getChildren()#add(new TextEllipse(...)#getBackgroundShape())
```

The ellipse does show up.

Why won't the ellipse and text show up if I just add the TextEllipse object?

Comment: Extend `Pane` or one of its subclasses. You need to add the text and ellipse to the node.

Comment: When I extend it with Pane or StackPane and add it as one of the pane's children, it refuses to show up? :(

Comment: Because you **still** didn't add the shape and text to the pane. Why did you leave out the line `getChildren().addAll(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
public class TextEllipse extends StackPane{
    private final Ellipse bubble;
    private final Text text;

    TextEllipse(String text, double x, double y)
    {            
        this.text = new Text(x, y, text);
        System.out.println(this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());
        bubble = new Ellipse (x, y, this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() + 5, 15);
        bubble.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        getChildren().addAll(bubble, this.text);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is to use a `StackPane`.

For example (and to make it easily reusable), you could define a abstract `TextShape` class which extends `StackPane`

```
public abstract class TextShape extends StackPane {

    private final Text text;
    private final Shape shape;

    public TextShape(final String t) {
        text = new Text(t);
        shape = createShape();          
        getChildren().addAll(shape, text);
    }

    abstract protected Shape createShape();

    public Text getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Shape getBackgroundShape() {
        return shape;
    }        

}
```

Then implement a concrete `TextShape`, e.g. `TextEllipse` by overriding the factory method:

```
public class TextEllipse extends TextShape {

    public TextEllipse(final String t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    protected Shape createShape() {
        final double PADDING = 10;
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.setRadiusX(getText().getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2 + PADDING);
        ellipse.setRadiusY(getText().getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2 + PADDING);
        ellipse.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        return ellipse;
    }        
}
```

Example use:

```
public class Example extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new TextEllipse("Hello World"));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this implementation, and when I run my program and add it to the pane, it doesn't show up. Neither does it show up when I add it to the scene.